# VEH inside class

Tags: c++, exception

I want to write a class for a vectored exception handler debugger. I am able to do it outside of a class, but the problem is that once I try to port it inside of a class I am unable add the VEH because of the handler function prototype it accepts

```
long __stdcall VEH(PEXCEPTION_POINTERS e);
```

and once it goes inside of the class, the 'this' pointer messes up the prototype

I can declare it as a 'static', but then I am not able to access the members of the class, which I absolutely need to do, and there is no way for me to pass a second parameter to the handler so i can access the current class instance like I could with a CreateThread thread

Is there any way to do this without having to store things globally? I would really need everything to be encapsulated within one instance of the class

Comment: I didn't get what you want to do, but as i understood, 
i is easy to do what you want by making global variable,  so static keyword outside class may be usef3ull, you can make global variable  that you can see only inside file it declarated

Comment: Yeah, but ideally everything would be encapsulated inside a class for cases such as wanting to create multiple instances of the class